# Get JMenuItems from JMenuBar

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I'm trying to retrieve the JMenuItems in my JMenuBar from a class which receives the JFrame as an argument. Ive done some reading and I think I understand that the JMenuBar contains JMenu but those do not contain the JMenuItems directly, correct?

Here what I have so far (obviously, it doesn't work!):

> JFrame mainWindow;
>
> [...]
>
> Component[] menus = mainWindow.getJMenuBar().getComponents();

So how could I obtain, lets say at best, an array of all the JMenuItems of my JFrame? I will then simply enable them one-by-one afterwards.

Thanks!

Comment: *"So how could I obtain, lets say at best, an array of all the JMenuItems of my JFrame? I will then simply enable them one-by-one afterwards."*  Use `Action` objects and store them in an array.  The way this question is phrased it has a distinct odor of 'bad design'..

Comment: I see your point but how would it be any better if those items are already stored in the JFrame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can get the JMenu and JMenuItem as well.

Use [JMenuBar#getMenu()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuBar.html#getMenu%28int%29) and [JMenu#getMenuComponent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html#getMenuComponent%28int%29) methods to get the desired output.

sample program:

```
JMenuBar menubar1 = getJMenuBar();
for (int i = 0; i < menubar1.getMenuCount(); i++) {
    JMenu menu1 = menubar1.getMenu(i);
    System.out.println("Menu:" + menu1.getText());
    for (int j = 0; j < menu1.getMenuComponentCount(); j++) {
        java.awt.Component comp = menu1.getMenuComponent(j);
        if (comp instanceof JMenuItem) {
            JMenuItem menuItem1 = (JMenuItem) comp;
            System.out.println("MenuItem:" + menuItem1.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The JMenu class has methods that [its API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html) will show that allow you to easily get the JMenuItems: `getItemCount()` and `getItem(int pos)`.  There's also `getMenuElements()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a bunch! This turned out to work great and was easier then expected :)

> ```
>           for (int i = 0; i < mainWindow.getJMenuBar().getMenuCount(); i++) {
>                 for (int j = 0; j < mainWindow.getJMenuBar().getMenu(i).getItemCount(); j ++) {
>                     if (mainWindow.getJMenuBar().getMenu(i).getItem(j) != null) {
>                         mainWindow.getJMenuBar().getMenu(i).getItem(j).setEnabled(true);
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
> ```

Comment: What if the menu has other submenus and those submenus have other submenus? You will need to do some recursive calling to handle that. What you have may work for simple cases, but just something to keep in mind ;-)